# C Programming - Prime Number Check

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and i'm wondering, why my code which job is to chceck if input number is prime.
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

bool prime(int);

int main()
{
    int x;
    x = getchar();
    if (x < 2)
        printf("its not prime\n");
    else
    {
        if (prime(x))
            printf("its prime\n");
        else
            printf("its not prime\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

bool prime(int x)
{
    for (int i = 2; i*i <= x; i++)
        if (x%i == 0)
        {
            return false;
            break;
        }
        else
            return true;
}
```

I don't know what i'm doing bad :/ Can you please help me? 
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You didn't specify what's "bad" about your code

Comment: What is the input, the output, and the expected output?

Comment: You want to know why your code checks if the input number is prime? Because that was the assignment?

Comment: `x = getchar();` - I think that's it.

Comment: Convert to decimal after `getchar()`: `x = x - '\0';`

Comment: Use `scanf()` to read a number, not `getchar()`.

Comment: oh, sory, for example it returns that 67 is not a prime number :/ i don't realy know why does that happen

Comment: You can't read 67 with `getchar`, unless you are inputting the character `'C'`

Comment: `x = getchar();` doesn't do what I think you think it does.

Comment: I'll also note that your `break;` is unnecessary and unreachable code, while your `return true;` will return too early.

Comment: If you type in 67, then getchar() reads one character - the character '6'. The Ascii value of that is 54 in decimal, which is not prime..

Comment: @Bartek - The `prime` function returns either true or false already at the first test. You have to check *all* values before returning true.

Comment: In `prime`, remove the `else`. (i.e. ensure the `return true` is _outside_ the loop). It may not be a true problem, but it's messy and suspect

Comment: @CraigEstey: It is a true problem. It reports any odd number as prime, even it it's not.

Comment: ok, thank you guys, it was all about getchar to scanf shift :D

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because `x=getchar()` will accept only one character and let's you type `2` then the value of `x` will be `50` and 50 is not prime number, so you will get result `not prime`(but you are expecting '`prime`) the reason is when you type `2` it will assign it's ascii value to x because x is `int` and you are giving `char`.(And for `bool` to run you have to include `stdbool.h` in your code)

Right code for prime number checking is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool prime(int);

int main()
{
int x;
scanf("%d",&x);
if (x < 2)
    printf("its not prime\n");
else
{
    if (prime(x))
        printf("its prime\n");
    else
        printf("its not prime\n");
}
return 0;
}

bool prime(int x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i*i <= x; i++){
        if (x%i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```